# How to make a restaurant chabot information send to a interface that people can view?

Tags: node.js, api, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making a chatbot on dialogflow that can fulfill basic needs of a restaurant (booking a table, ordering food, maybe leaving a review etc.)

I have been able to make reservations for restaurants, and I know how to extract necessary information for ordering food, but what I don't know/ fully understand is the process of taking that information and the restaurant being able to see it on the other side. When I did restaurant bookings for example, the way the restaurant could see a booking would be on a Google Calendar API I connected to the dialogflow agent.

Here is an example of how the conversation would go to maybe further clarify:

I know how to do this:

```
User: I'd like to buy a small Dark roast coffee
Bot: Okay, is that everything?
User: Yes 
Bot: Okay, Your small Dark roast is being made!
```

But this is completely useless if it goes no where and the restaurant can't see the order on the other side (ie: can't see it on a order screen or a program)

I know this involves some sort of fulfillment in the inline editor or possibly a heroku API, but I'm pretty new to web development so I don't fully understand how to make this order to go through so the restaurant could see it.

Any suggestions or advice?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to exchange data between the browser and the server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store data/dialogs to the backend.

You need also two roles in the frontend. The customer and the restaurant. Whitch means, that you have to implement authentication (Login - Logout - Signup), and authorization based on the user.